# Clojure boolean true or false

Tags: clojure

So I've been teaching myself some basic Clojure, but I'm little stuck with the below.

I have managed to put together some code which tests if the inputed number is a prime. (although it doesn't completely work)

```
(defn is-prime [x]
(loop [n 2]
(cond
 (< n x) (if (not= 0 (mod x n))
           (recur (inc n))
           (println "false"))
 :else (println "true"))))

(is-prime 5)
```

Returns true as expected. However my goal now is to get it to return true or false in the screen not with my print lines. I need the boolean to be true or false without the text I'm adding.

Comment: Hi, no that was the first thing I tried. And you've lost me with the second part. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure why you did not manage to simply change `(println "true")` to `true`. This works just fine:

```
(defn is-prime [x]
(loop [n 2]
  (cond
   (< n x) (if (not= 0 (mod x n))
             (recur (inc n))
             false)
   :else true)))

  (is-prime 5) ;; true

  (filter is-prime (range 2 15)) ;; (2 3 5 7 11 13)
```

On another note, in clojure, `nil` and `false` are the only two 'falsey' values, so this function would work the same if you change the `if` sexp to:

```
(when-not (zero? (mod x n))
  (recur (inc n)))
```

Here is a another, slightly more 'clojuristic' way of doing the same:

```
(defn is-prime [x]
  (cond
    (<= x 1) false
    (= x 2) true
    :else (every? #(pos? (mod x %)) (range 2 (inc (Math/sqrt x))))))
```

So if you want a function that generates all primes between `n` and `m`, do:

```
(defn all-primes [n m]
  (filter is-prime (range n m)))

(all-primes 90 110) ;; (97 101 103 107 109)
```

Comment: I am running it in REPL.it, this is the platform I've been told to run it on.

Comment: Using your above worked, I must have missed brackets or something when converting it. Big thanks Shlomi.

Comment: Shlomi, the filter infront of the is-prime, is it possible to allow the range to be decided on input? for example changing it so (prime-filter 2 15)?

Comment: @JamesBurton, of course it is. You could read a number from keyboard, or you could pass it as a parameter to another function

Comment: Ive added the below to read from the is-prime function. But it reads true, false etc not the numbers. How do I got about getting all the primes between the two ranges?
  (defn is-prime [x]
  (loop [n 2]
    (cond
       (< n x) (if (not= 0 (mod x n))
               (recur (inc n))
               false)
     :else true)))


  (defn prime-seq [n, m]
    (for [x (range n m)] (is-prime x)) 
  
    )

Comment: just use `filter` as I showed above. If you use `for` you are 'saving' the result of `is-prime` instead of treating it as a predicate. Other than that, for new questions please make a new post, and if this answered your current question please accept.

Comment: im trying to get use to the functions. Are you able to answer it on this post just so you have the context on my situation? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: just for future reference, your is-prime doesn't fully work, it says 0 and 1 is a prime number. And yes I accept :)

Comment: Right, silly edge case. Fixed for negatives also, good catch!

Comment: @JamesBurton To *accept* an answer, click on the tick you see by its top margin. This rewards the answerer and lets the rest of us know the question has been dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

**just for fun / irrelevant to the question**

to see the power of clojure, here is the mind-stretching exercise with lazy primes seq generation:

```
user>
(def primes (cons 2 (filter (fn [n]
                              (let [sqn (Math/sqrt n)]
                                (not-any? #(zero? (rem n %))
                                          (take-while #(<= % sqn) primes))))
                            (iterate #(+ 2 %) 3))))
#'user/primes

user> (last (take 10000 primes))
104729

user> (take 20 primes)
(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71)

user> (last (take 10000 primes))
104729

user> (last (take 100000 primes))
1299709
```

Answer (score 0):

You can often use `and` and `or` to get rid of explicit `false` and `true`. Having got rid of the `println`s as [Shlomi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47991684/1562315) does, this gives us ...

```
(defn is-prime [x]
  (loop [n 2]
    (or (>= n x)
        (and (not= 0 (mod x n))
             (recur (inc n))))))
```

To me, this is clearer.

---

By the way, Clojure predicates end in `?` by convention: `is-prime?` instead of `is-prime`.